# Who can see other user's Deleted questions and how?

Tags: support

The Deleted answers are automatically visible to users who have [Access To Moderator Tools](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) Privilege.

But who can see Deleted questions of other users and how?

These posts seem related but I couldn't get any clear answer:

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

[Enable searching with deleted:1 for 10k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users)

**Update:**

**deleted:1** or **deleted:yes** doesn't help in searching Deleted Questions of others. Using them one can see only his/her own Deleted posts:

> Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted
>   content

**deleted:all** doesn't seem working properly, it returns Deleted as well other posts (not of other users but own posts).

Comment: The privilege you mentioned is applicable to both question and answer post. Users having privileges "access to moderate tools" can search `deleted:1` or `deleted:yes`. Visit [Advance searching help page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: @Pandya deleted:1 or deleted:yes doesn't help in searching Deleted Questions of others. Using them one can see only his/her own Deleted posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Users with access to moderator tools](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can view deleted questions, if they have a link to a deleted question. They can also see the deleted answers on a post, if there are any. They can also use `deleted:1`, `deleted:all`, etc to search *amongst their own* deleted posts.

♦  moderators can see the deleted posts of a user alongside their other posts from the user profile (activity tab) directly.

Comment: Well so do you mean other than ♦ moderators no body can see a Deleted question if they don't have it's link? If we search words of the deleted question it doesn't appear in search results..right?

Comment: @YDS Yup, they won't appear.