# Advanced search syntaxes?

Tags: support, search

I think there are many advanced search syntaxes which might be helpful while searching something.

From [Who can see other user's Deleted questions and how?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/who-can-see-other-users-deleted-questions-and-how), I came to know that one can search own deleted Q's using **deleted:1** or **deleted:yes**

From chatroom, I learnt that **user:me search_text** can be used to search among own posts and **is:q** or **is:a** can be used to specify if we want to search in Questions or Answers.

Are there some other advanced search syntaxes which can be helpful while searching something on Hinduism SE?

Comment: It will be good to limit the question scope to specific query. There are probably many advance search options. Few of them are listed in [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). Some options are also listed in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=), by expanding the "Tips".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've missed [my comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/who-can-see-other-users-deleted-questions-and-how#comment4609_1118) to [your question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1118/277) you mentioned in [the question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1385/277).

What you're looking is documented at Help Center Page : [**How do I search?**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

You will also see "Advance Search Tips" at the right panel while searching:

> [image]