# Is it possible to get a list of closed questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Is it possible to get a list of all closed questions?

Comment: Yes, just go through [help center article on How do I Search?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/searching). For filtering closed questions, use `closed:yes`

Comment: @Paṇḍyā Thanks. I have checked and it is working. If you wish you can convert that to an answer. Might be useful for a few like me :D

Comment: Although looks like I have asked a trivial Q but I have decided to undelete it because I feel the info might be useful to at least some users.@Paṇḍyā

Comment: As of now I don't have access to moderator tools, so I'm not sure if that search criteria also displays deleted questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advanced search syntaxes?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/advanced-search-syntaxes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just click on "Advance Search Tips" while searching:

> [image]

And you'll find some useful syntax as follows:

> [image]

As highlighted, you can filter questions based on their status, here you can use

#### `closed:yes` or `closed:1` to filter questions which are closed.

For detailed information on searching and filtering posts based on various parameters, visit [**How do I search?**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/searching) help-center article